# running shall command with ansible

Tags: ansible

i am new to Ansible,  and have write .yml file to empty a file, just like ">file_name"

```
---

tasks:


  - name: Empty Log Files greater then 400M



     shell: 'find "{{ item }}" -name "messages*" -size +400M -exec sh -c '> {}' \;'

    with_items:
      - /var/log
      - /var/opt
      - /var/spool/mail
    ignore_errors: yes
```

and i am getting this following error

> ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
>
> The error appears to have been in
>   '/tmp/clean.yml': line 7, column 11, but may
>   be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
>
> The offending line appears to be:
>
> - name: Delete Log Files greater then 400M
>      shell: 'find "{{ item }}" -name "messages*" -size +400M -exec sh -c '> {}' \;'
>           ^ here We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with missing quotes.  Always quote template expression
>     brackets when they start a value. For instance:
>
>   with_items:
>
>   - {{ foo }}
>
> Should be written as:
>
> ```
> with_items:
>   - "{{ foo }}"
> ```
>
> exception type:  exception: mapping
>   values are not allowed in this context   in "", line
>   7, column 11

where im getting it wrong?

Comment: Hi...WC to SO! I will suggest to use ansible `find:` module instead of shell command. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html...the yml syntax plays an important role in ansible....you should validate your syntax using ansible` --syntax-check` option

Comment: Have you checked that line in question? It contains a single quote in the middle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly refer below playbook as a reference for the same.

```
---
- name: play to check the file size
  hosts: "{{ servers }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Recursively find /tmp files older than 4 weeks and equal or greater than 1 megabyte
      find:
        paths: "{{ item }}"
        age: 4w
        size: 1m
        recurse: yes
      with_items:
      - path_1
      - path_2
      - path_3
```